# How to manage Drupal custom modules?

Tags: php, git, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Imagine this scenario: you use a custom Drupal module in Drupal-7 website A and in Drupal-7 website B and you make changes to the custom module in website A. If you want these updates in Drupal website B, you'll have to:

1. Push the changes from A to the remote server (At the moment we use a GIT repo to keep track of our custom drupal modules)
2. Pull the changes in website B (and other websites that also use the custom module)

Is there a way so that I don't have to keep track of all the websites where a custom module is installed? In other words: is it possible to get an notice in website B that there is a new version of the custom module, just like it would be if it was a default contrib Drupal module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you'll get without writing something custom is the [Feature Server](https://drupal.org/project/fserver) module

> This module allows you to share features and custom modules on your own website. It lets you create projects and releases, and it produces an update XML feed compatible with the update module in core. In a way it's a highly simplified version of the project module.

There's only a release for Drupal 6, but you can use that version to provide feeds for D7 modules too.